# choregraphe with pepper version 2.4 and 2.5

Tags: robotics, pepper, choregraphe

I could not save my project in the pepper. After trying with lot of options, I guess this might be due to the version issues. I found that the version of naqi is 2.5.3.3 where as my choregraphe is 2.8.2.
I tried to upgrade the application in pepper to 2.8. It is saying that all the applications are updated but actually the version remains the same (2.5.3)

Therefore , I tried downloading the choregraphe-pepper with 2.5 or 2.4. and I found them but both are related to nao not pepper.

I downloaded from https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/resources/software/language/en-gb

Can anyone provide me the correct link to download choregraphe- pepper version 2.4 or 2.5.? or can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is the version of NAOqi on Pepper in the end? You should take a Choregraphe in the same version number.

Comment: Hi Victor! It's 2.5.3.3 but I can not find choregraphe with version 2.5.3.3. can you please share the link to download the version 2.5.3.3? The link I found was not correct. It is for nao not pepper.

Answer (score 2):

For Pepper, you should be using Choregraphe 2.5, which is indeed for Pepper (though technically it also works on NAO). There is no NAOqi 2.8 for Pepper.

Your issue here is that a project created with Choregraphe 2.8 will have a .pml file with a version format of 5, which older versions of Choregraphe do not support. However, most of the time apart from the format_version flag there are no important differences between the format (presumably there will be some if you use some of the new Choregraphe 2.8 features), you can just open your .pml file with a text editor, change

```
<Package name="your-package-id" format_version="5">
```

to

```
<Package name="your-package-id" format_version="4">
```

... and you will be able to open it with Choregraphe 2.5 (unless you used some unusual features).